# Access filesystem using js within grails project

Tags: javascript, file, grails

For learning purposes I created a toy project using grails.
In this project I would like to play an mp3 file in one of my views.
I found an html5/flash mp3 player. But when the music is supposed to play, I have a question.

The HTML 5 player is in the project/web-app/js folder. Everything else is in its normal place.
When I try to access a file, let's say "test.mp3" using just the name and extension of the file, where this file is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file should be relative to whatever your current path is.

That is, if you're at

`localhost:8080/myapp/test/test1`, and you reference `test.mp3`, `test.mp3` would have to be in the `test1` directory. You can use absolute paths, such as `/sounds/test.mp3` to reference from the root, but a better solution would be to use `${resource(...)}` probably.

Here's the [resource documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.1.x/ref/Tags/resource.html).

Comment: ok, let's say i want to use the first way.
where will i found test/test1 folder?
In the web-app folder?